# How to create a new command that allows texstudio to display a note in the paper in the structure menu?

Tags: texstudio

I created the following command to create colored notes in my paper :

```
\newcommand{\notes}[1]{\textcolor{red}{Note : #1}}
```

however, I do not know how to force texstudio to display these notes in the structure menu for a convenient go to note feature. How do I create a new command that allows texstudio to display a note in the paper in the structure menu?

Note : I am also worried that general solutions may not work for the specific package I am using, which is sffms.

Comment: This is completely an editor thing and has nothing to do with the LaTeX side.

Comment: Instead of create that command in texstudio, check the [todonotes package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) that can do what you want. 

In the other hand, in the structure window you're able to see the hierarchy of your document and also the labels you are using. If you want to program something more, you should contact the `TeXstudio` [developers](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) to see what recommend you.

Comment: You can use something like `\newcommand{\notes}[1]{\textcolor{red}{Note : #1}} %TODO: Note: Text` and that will appear in the `structure menu` of `TexStudio`. You need a new version (`> 2.8`).